# Add badge description on badge page

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-description

We all wonder from time to time on which circumstances we get a certain badge. Some ask about it on meta. Then we can point to the [list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/).

But wouldn't it be best to place the description of every badge where it belongs in the first place?

[image: badge page]

Copy editor for instance has a lot bigger description than just *Edited 500 posts*. 
And don't get me started on the Epic and Legendard badge: Even some meta posts don't explain the conditions correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like they could just put a link to the FAQ entry there, maybe just something simple like

> more...

after the short description.

Comment: +1 I'm always up for **MOAR badges!**