# Research Assistant - update to "Edited 50 different tag wikis bodies"?

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-wiki, wording, edit-badges

Research Assistant badge [is defined as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Research Assistant
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Edit 50 different tag wiki bodies
> - Tag wiki *excerpt* edits do not count
> - You can edit an existing tag wiki or create a new one
> - Edits to tag wiki excerpts do **not** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484))

However, the text shown in [the badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1656/research-assistant) is:

> Edited 50 tag wikis.

The need to be **different** tag wikis is something that creates confusion. Also, the fact that it has to be **bodies** (excerpts do not count).

For this, I suggest updating the description to something like...

> Edited 50 different tag wikis bodies.

It is still something short and avoids confusion. Don't you think it is better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add badge description on badge page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167845/add-badge-description-on-badge-page)

Comment: I do not think it is really duplicate, as I mention this specific badge and to make the explanation more clear.

Comment: The tag wiki *body* is the actual **tag wiki**. The tag wiki *excerpt* is the **tag wiki excerpt**. This naming and usage is consistent.

Comment: I am not claiming for consistency, but for utility : ) I am asking the text in the badge page to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

No. The existing wording is lucid and unambiguous: "Edited 50 tag wikis".

- Does it need the word "different" to make it unambiguous? No more than "ring a thousand doorbells" or "talk to a thousand people" does. If I ring the same doorbell a thousand times, or talk to the same person a thousand times, have I done what is described? No, that is "ring a doorbell a thousand times" and "talk to a person a thousand times" (or, in the case of tag wikis, "edit a tag wiki 50 times").
- Does it need the word "bodies" to make it unambiguous? No, the word "body" is superfluous because the tag wiki body *is* the tag wiki, and a tag wiki excerpt is not a tag wiki. (On a side note, personally I'm not convinced the word "excerpt" really evokes the intended function, because this bit of text is not just any old extract from the wiki but is supposed to encapsulate its main points. Hence we might consider calling it something else such as "tag wiki summary" or "tag description". But that's another matter: the names are what they are, their meaning and usage is clear, and there's no ambiguity.)
- "wikis bodies" doesn't make sense. One wiki body, a number of wiki bodies. No need to pluralize "wiki" too. If you really want to do so, the "s" needs to be possessive (the bodies of the wikis), in which case we would have to say "tag wikis' bodies", which is even more cumbersome.

No, please leave it just as it is, lucid and unambiguous: "Edited 50 tag wikis".

Comment: I disagree. It took me 2 weeks to realize that my tag wiki excerpt edits didn't count as tag wiki page edits. I assumed that the edits counted since excerpts are shown on the tag page.

Answer (score -2):

My answer to the question ***Don't you think it is better?*** is like so:

'Edited 50 *different* tag wikis *bodies*.' is way better, and the current text for it (='Edited 50 tag wikis.') is clearly incomplete ... and misleading.

Note: if this ever gets implemented, one might even want to include the italics format as I did here in this answer.