# Does a copy editor with rep below 2K still earn any rep for a wiki body edit of a tag that that user never suggested an edit for before?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Apart from the great question about "[Research Assistant - update to "Edited 50 different tag wikis bodies"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177047)", a related question is like so: "Does a copy editor with rep below 2K still earn any rep for a wiki body edits of a tag that that user never suggested an edit for before?"

About a copy editor: Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits) ... Combined with "each accepted edit suggestion results in a reputation Increase of +2", this implies that you did gain 500 x 2 = 1000 points because of those 500 accepted edits ... I assume.

Reason why I'm not sure (without further investigation): a copy editor doesn't get any more +2 reps for each additional suggested edit that got accepted. So how would one explain/motivate that accepted edit suggestions for tag wikis and/or excerpts still results in +2 reps then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the facts after [my 'new' tag wiki 'body' edit suggestion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/54939) got accepted (and knowing that my rep on Drupal.SE is currently around 1,860 ... so **below 2K**):

- **I did NOT get any rep anymore** (like +2 for anybody who is not yet a copy editor).
- **It did increase my counter** related to the "Research Assistant" tag.

Nathan Tuggy (with current rep on SO = 2,118, so **above 2K**) added as comment "*I've had Copy Editor for months now (I have more than 1150 edits on Stack Overflow total), and I still get +2 for every wiki edit. So this cannot be correct*". The explanation for that case/scenario seems to be related to "has a rep of +2K": because of that rep, no extra rep (like +2 for each edit) is gained anymore, so there is like "room left" for earning rep via tag wiki edits (below the cap of 1000 rep).

PS (to be clear): my assumption is "you are a copy editor already", so as in my second part of my question: you did already gain a rep of 500 x 2 = 1000 by only those 500 accepted edits.

Comment: I've had Copy Editor for months now (I have more than 1150 edits on SO total), and I still get +2 for every wiki edit. So this cannot be correct.

Comment: There's actually one other way you might get Copy Editor without 2k rep and without maxing out your suggested edit rep: make a lot of CW edits. Doing so should, in rare cases, allow gaining more rep from suggestions.

Comment: I'm assuming CW edits = Community Wiki edits, right? I'm not (yet) familiar with such edits, but would like to learn more about them. Any link suggestion about that in the help pages? Or some link on meta.SE or SO where I can find a link or so to start such CW edit?

Comment: There's a basic description in the [Help Center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), and there's a bit more in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). [tag:community-wiki] should have some more scattered around.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they do. The badge is not relevant to your ability to earn reputation.

The problem you're running into is **you can only earn up to 1,000 reputation from suggested edits**. Wherever they come from, you cap out at 1,000. You seem to have hit that cap, and that's why you're no longer receiving reputation for the edits you're making.

Comment: Is there any way to tell how close one is to hitting this cap, out of curiosity?

Comment: I believe you can still see how much reputation you've earned from suggested edits via the `/reputation` page. I'm not sure how accurate it is, though.

Comment: Looks about right from here: 936 rep from suggested edits.

Comment: Hm, 1150 edits (as in comment to my answer, that should have resulted in at least 1000 rep increase also, no? So why only 936 then? Could there be some relationship with REMOVED resp of -2 each? Assume you would do 32 more suggested edits, they all get accepted, so it results in 32x2=64 rep increase ... From then on, will you still get +2 rep for tag wiki edits? The bets are open ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The 936 is Nathan's amount that he has gained from suggested edits. You've hit the cap already. Tag wiki suggestions are still suggested edits in the system, so once you've hit the 1,000 cap, then no you will not gain reputation from tag wiki edits. If a post gets deleted, the system automatically recalculates and one of your edits which was capped will change to be +2 instead of 0 to compensate, or you just lose the 2 reputation if none were capped (at that point you can regain it again).

Comment: 1150 edits only result in 936 rep because of suggested edits? Why not at least 1000? Get my point about Nathan's case?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Because he has 2,000 reputation. He doesn't suggest edits anymore, he can make them directly without being reviewed. Thus he does not earn reputation from regular edits. He can only earn reputation by suggesting tag wiki edits. And users who hit the 20,000 mark and have full edit privileges on tag wikis too cannot ever earn reputation from suggested edits again.

Comment: That makes it clear, but then that also seem to explain why his comment to my answer is slightly different from my situation: hè has +2K rep, not me ...

Comment: His comment is only pointing out that Copy Editor is not the reason why you'd stop gaining reputation from suggested edits. There are *lots* of users who have Copy Editor who have not maxed out their reputation gained from suggested edits. It's just that in *your* situation you managed to max it out and gain the badge before you ever gained full editing privileges. That actually [doesn't happen all that often](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/313634/copy-editor-badges-awarded-with-without-full-edit-privileges).