# Why don't tag excerpt edits count towards the Research Assistant badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, edit-badges

The description shown for the [Research Assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/173/research-assistant) is

> Edited 50 tag wikis.

According to the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/351462), this does **not** include edits to tag wiki excerpts. It's [been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177047/research-assistant-update-to-edited-50-different-tag-wikis-bodies) that the description be updated to make this distinction more clear, an idea I fully agree with. However, that post got me wondering.

***Why don't excerpt edits count towards the badge?***

When creating the badge in 2012, [ex-employee waffles said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/351462) he wanted to encourage wiki edits over excerpt editing, but this doesn't seem to have worked. Only 5 users on Meta Stack Exchange have earned the badge since its creation 5 years ago.

[image: 5 users earned badge]

It seems a bit silly to award users for editing tag wikis, rather than awarding users for contributing to a tag's usage guidelines, which is arguably the most important part ad visible of a tag.

Comment: Well, strong argument is that excerpt is short, so editing it is almost trivial compared to full wiki edit. Maybe worth asking to add bronze version of the badge for editing 50 excerpts, but I do agree it's not something worthy of a silver badge.